# In Julia: How do I get the name of the currently running program?

Tags: python, julia

In Python 3.6+ the following works:

```
import sys
print(f"Program name is {sys.argv[0]}")
Program name is C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py
```

How do I do this in Julia?

Comment: Although it is perfectly fine (for archive reasons) to ask questions and answer them yourself right away (as you have done multiple times now) I would try to restrict myself to questions that can't be answered by simply looking into the julia docs.

Comment: If I enter, program file name, into the Julia 1.0 doc search engine, it is very slow on my machine to return the hits.  It then returns 1,561 hits.  None of the top 5 hits appear to have the answer.  If I enter, Julia program file name, into the stackoverflow Search box, the answer comes back almost instantly.  The second hit is my question.  Since the Julia way of returning the program file name is different from other languages, e.g., Python, and it is possible to forget a constant name, it seems reasonable to use stackoverflow's quick search engine for archival purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Julia program file, this works:

```
println("Program name is ", PROGRAM_FILE)

""" Output
Program name is StackQuestion.jl
"""
```

In the Julia 1.0 REPL there is no output:

```
julia> print("The program name is ", PROGRAM_FILE)
The program name is
```

This should not be a problem since getting the program name is something one would typically want to do within their running program.

A useful tip from the Julia 1.0 docs relating to the program file name is:
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#

"How do I check if the current file is being run as the main script?

When a file is run as the main script using `julia file.jl` one might want to activate extra functionality like command line argument handling. A way to determine that a file is run in this fashion is to check `if abspath(PROGRAM_FILE) == @__FILE__` is true."

Comment: Note that `PROGRAM_FILE` is a constant and won't change when including a script in the REPL. To get the file name of the current julia script, use `@__FILE`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  I think you meant `@__FILE__` or maybe I am missing something.